# Accessing a view inside ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add an Horizontal Progress bar to my view like so:

res/menu.xml

```
<item   android:id="@+id/menuItemProgress"
        android:title="Progress"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/component_cancellable_progressbar"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

component_cancellable_progressbar.xml

```
<FrameLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/searchProgressWrapper"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<ProgressBar    android:id="@+id/searchProgress"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                style="@style/Custom.Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:max="100" />
<ImageView      android:id="@+id/cancelSearch"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="8dp" 
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" 
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</FrameLayout>
```

How do I access this ProgressBar from within an Action (To make it Visisble / Invisible / Progress) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate() and after you can simply access it via findViewById() like normal. Problem was caused by something else.

Comment: do you mind documented what was the underlying cause for this behaviour?

Comment: @max4ever be sure it's created. Probably you need to use `postDelayed` to wait till view of AB item is rendered.

Comment: Sorry, I eventually got bored of using the standard Android API for ActionBar's and created my own custom implementation. It's not that difficult and would recommend it for anyone doing any medium to large scale app that uses interesting things on the ActionBar.

Answer (score 5):

it is possible to get the view of the action item.

however, do note that sometimes action items get to be inside the overflow menu so you might get a null instead.

so, how can you do it?

here's a sample code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
  getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      final View syncItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_search);
      ...
```

this was tested when using actionBarSherlock library, on android 4.1.2 and android 2.3.5 .

another alternative is to use a more extensive way , used on the [showcaseView library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView), [here](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/blob/master/library/src/com/espian/showcaseview/ShowcaseView.java) .

Comment: this solved my problem.  Using the handler is required to ensure that the menu item has been added to the view hierarchy (by being enqueued after onCreateOptionsMenu() is complete)

Answer (score 2):

You can override onCreateOptionsMenu and catch your view there:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  menu.getItem(0).getActionView();
  ...
```

or by searching the id

`View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();`

I inserted a custom drop down menu in the action bar and was able to gain control of it this way.

Answer (score -1):

Following is a very helpful link for actionBar.Hope you will able to implement what you want.

http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/actionbar-design-pattern-example-for-android/

```
public class ActionBar extends FrameLayout {

      private ProgressBar mProgress;



      public ActionBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        mInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       FrameLayout barView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);

        addView(barView);

       mProgress = (ProgressBar) barView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_progress);

    public void showProgressBar() { ... }

    public void hideProgressBar() { ... }

    public boolean isProgressBarVisible() { ... }


}
```

Then from your activity control your progressbar like following.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ActionBar mActionBar;



    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mActionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);

        mActionBar.showProgressbar()

     }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't sorry, I'm trying to find out how to find a view in the v11 ActionBar component rather than a "build-it-yourself" Action Bar.

Comment: Again, I want to know how to access a view attached to the view in android.app.ActionBar NOT in a custom ActionBar.